# Xpages: Code a new page button so that I can repopulate some fields in new Xpage

Tags: xpages

This seems like it should be easy to do but I cannot get it done.

I have an Xpage called Location. There are two general types, A and B. I have a series of views for A and B. They are the same except for the value of that one field.

In the views I want my "New Location" button to automatically populate the type to A or B, depending on whether the user is in one of the A views or B views.

Seems like I would set a scoped variable and then check for that on document creation, but it doesn't seem to work. What is the best practice to do this?

Comment: I believe I found my mistake. I was using requestScope, but it seems there is a bug in that this won't carry on to the next page; I changed to sessionScope and it worked. I cleared out the sessionScope variable after I have used it.

Comment: It's not a bug. requestScope lives only during the request itself. Opening a new XPages you need at least sessionScope. Even viewScope doesn't "survive" in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Jesse Gallagher's frostillicus framework on OpenNTF (XPages Scaffolding - http://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Scaffolding&SessionID=DN6QBBFGEB) includes flashScopes, which give the facility to pass information from one page to another and get cleared when the page is loaded.

Comment: +1 for flashScope. Here's the original blog post: http://www.bleedyellow.com/blogs/andyc/entry/a_flash_scope_for_xpages?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

You can use sessionScope variable to transfer data from one XPage to another.

A better approach might be to use URL parameter for your case.

Add for example `&type=A` to your URL like

```
http://server/database.nsf/Location.xsp?action=newDocument&type=A
```

Then you can read this parameter in your destination XPage with `param.type` like

```
var type = param.type;
```

The disadvantage of sessionScope is that it's the same for all browser tabs. So, you need to delete it right after usage in this case. Using an URL parameter instead you don't have to think about that.